# Admin SDK update returning code 5: no entity to update

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to update an existing document in firestore. The document definitely exists. The data being sent from the client has all the data from the document itself (every field and value as well as the document id auto-generated by firestore).

I have tried each value of data that gets passed to the Firebase function: data.id (auto-gen id), `data.email`, `data.name`, to create a reference to the document to update, but still getting the error response. However, the .then and .catch blocks are both being executed each time the function fires.

As I said before, the document exists in the database in the 'users' collection. How do I reference that from the admin SDK?

Here is the function being called:

```
exports.createAssetMux = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({
        streamID: '98273498237'
    }).then(
        console.log('update success')
    ).catch(error => {
        console.log('error message: ', error)
    });
});
```

Here is the error message I am getting in the terminal:

```
error message:  Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update: app: "dev~firebase-app"
path <
  Element {
    type: "users"
    name: "kPuVNXsFFIyhs3Qad06B"
  }
>

  code: 5,
  details: 'no entity to update: app: "firebase-app"\n' +
    'path <\n' +
    '  Element {\n' +
    '    type: "users"\n' +
    '    name: "kPuVNXsFFIyhs3Qad06B"\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    '>\n',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'content-type' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the error messages from the terminal. Currently running locally using the emulators.

Comment: It looks like you have something misconfigured "dev~live-from-868ea" doesn't look like a proper app Id, also I’m unsure if you redacted the error code but my-firestore doesn't look valid. Did you tried to write docs with the same function to verify that you are actually accessing your database?. I can see that you are also asking a bunch of different questions on different comments and this is not a good approach to keep the case as focused and concise as possible. Please read the [How To ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doc.

Comment: Yeah, I was posting after a long day, meant to redact both of them. My bad. Anyways, what is the proper method for configuring the app id? or will it always be that app id when in dev mode? I'm pretty sure I need to get rid of the ~dev part, just can't figure out how. I have tried to write with the same function, it hits the .then() block and responds with success message, but nothing is being created in the db.

Comment: Ok, lets debug this by parts. The overall concept is to have a Cloud Function that writes into Firebase Firestore databse right? Are you at this point able to deploy a Cloud Function and interact with your database? i.e. following the [quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

Comment: I am able to deploy the function. It executes with a 200 status, but nothing updates in the db. But yes, that is correct, that is the overall concept I am going for here. Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: To ensure your document actually exists, can you try running something like: `admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('yourDocId').get().then((snap) => console.log(snap.exists))` ?

Comment: Snap.exists returns false for me. I know the document exists in the database collection I am trying to get to, but I think in the development environment, the admin sdk is pointing towards the wrong db/app. So I guess this question has been narrowed down to a way to configure that properly to point to an app with out the `dev~` part.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result), you need to return a promise that resolves with the data you want to send back to the client.  If you start some async work without dealing with the promise (`update()` returns a promise), then the function will shut down and the work won't complete.

```
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({
        streamID: '98273498237'
    }).then(
        console.log('update success')
        return { your: "response" }
    ).catch(error => {
        console.log('error message: ', error)
        return { your: "error" }
    });
```

You should return a response that makes sense for your client app.

In order to write effective cloud functions, you will definitely need to understand how JavaScript promises work.

Comment: ok. i have updated my function with the return statements, and i agree, i'll make sure to keep writing better code and understanding this more. but that wasn't an issue with the function here. the issue is the document reference path, for some reason it isn't referencing the proper path and comes up empty handed.

Answer (score -1):

Gee, it would be nice if there was an eslint plugin to check for unreturned promises (or code paths failing to call response.send() ) similar to the way eslint-plugin-promise checks for nested promises

Better to get a lint error than a runtime bug